# Scheduling Web Audio with Precision

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have music app developed using [MIDI.js](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js)

Below is my simplified code / logic to play notations using setTimeout.

```
function playMelody()
{
var notes = [49,50,51,52,53,54,55,76,80,45,68,56,87] //more than 1000
var time = [1,1.5,1,2,3,0.5,0.75,0.66,0.78,1.25,1.35,0.75,0.75] //more than 1000, time in seconds for each note value.
var ctxt=MIDI.getContext().currentTime;
var delay = time[0],l=notes.length,j=0;
function play()
{       
         if (j < l) 
         {            
                MIDI.noteOn(0,notes[j],75,ctxt+delay);  
                delay = delay + time[j];    
                j++;                                
         }      

setTimeout(play,time[j]);
}
play(); 
}

playMelody();
```

Recently I come across below article on Scheduling Web Audio with Precision.
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/

As per article, this method of scheduling note events is also useful for lower configuration devices.
I want to implement this method of scheduling events in my app, please help me to replace my logic with one described in the article

I have implemented in this way but I am not sure if it is correct or not.

```
function playMelody()
{
var notes = [49,50,51,52,53,54,55,76,80,45,68,56,87] //more than 1000
var time = [1,1.5,1,2,3,0.5,0.75,0.66,0.78,1.25,1.35,0.75,0.75] //more than 1000, time in seconds for each note value.
var ctxt=MIDI.getContext().currentTime;
var delay = time[0],l=notes.length,j=0;
function play()
{       
    while(delay+ctxt < MIDI.getContext().currentTime+4)
    {
        if (j < l) 
         {            
                MIDI.noteOn(0,notes[j],75,ctxt+delay);  
                delay = delay + time[j];    
                j++;                                
         }

    }
 setTimeout(play,2000);
}
 playMelody();
}
```

Comment: have you tried doing it yourself? stack overflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: I have added my code, but I am not sure if it is correct or not